Book recommendation for classical mechanics (a comparison)
I have found some classical mechanics book recommendation but not found the answer.
Recently , I was going through the two books on classical mechanics by John R Taylor and Kleppner - Kolenkow online .
I found that Taylor covers wide variety of topics than Kleppner and have those topics also which are in Kleppner.
I have a sort of freshman physics knowledge and wants to start ahead , so which book should I start with if I want some rigorous and proof based approaches ?
In other words which book in the above two (considering their common topics only) is more rigorous and have more derivation based approaches?
As of this question , it addresses the books for "advanced" classical mechanics (i.e only for Hamiltonian and Lagrange mechanics) .Also, there is no mention of the books I have mentioned.

This question is similar to: Book about classical mechanics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@LukasNullmeier I have edited the question and told how it was different. I am just looking for the answer which compares the books I have mentioned in the mentioned aspects .

If you're going through the two books, thank surely you can find out which one you like better?

Kleppner and Kolenkow is more rigorous mathematically and covers the topics it touches upon in appreciable depth. Taylor's text perhaps covers a wider range of topics at a slightly shallower level and with less mathematical sophistication. Also, the problems in Kleppner and Kolenkow are somewhat more challenging (in my opinion). I know your question pertains only to those two texts, but I would also recommend Thornton and Marion's Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems. It has the mathematical rigor of Kleppner and Kolenkow and the range of Taylor, but assumes the same level of preparation.

So , if I  plan to learn Hamiltonian mechanics and further with that rigor , should I buy Thornton and Marion?

I'd say it's the way to go out of the three! And if you were so inclined, you can easily find PDFs of the book and the solutions manual (valuable since it sounds like you're self-studying). Hold on to all three, though, because each will invariably cover a certain topic more clearly than the others, and you'll return to them all many times in the future.

Got it !! Thanks for the suggestions

No problem. I'm curious to see what other's have to say.
